# cannot change open file limit

Tags: 14.04, nginx, ulimit

On ubuntu 14.04 production web server, I set as below:

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
* soft nproc 65535
* hard nproc 65535
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session optional                        pam_umask.so
session required        pam_unix.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so
session required        pam_limits.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session optional                        pam_umask.so
session required        pam_unix.so
session required        pam_limits.so
```

Even after reboot, ulimit -n still output 1024. Could one of configs below caused it?

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.core.somaxconn = 16384
fs.file-max = 65535

$ sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 65535

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1026931
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1026931
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm in the same boat and NOTHING I've found is helping.

Comment: Found the answer, finally: https://superuser.com/a/1200818/885325

Answer (score 1):

check if there is not another process launching and changing the ulimit before like here with supervisor : https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors

Comment: sadly there's no /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf or /etc/default/supervisor in my ubuntu 14.04. Do I need to install supervisord first?